Fingerprint refusing to work on Arch?
I'm at my wits end trying to get my fingerprint to work on Arch. I'm using a P14s Gen 5, have enrolled and verified my fingerprint with fprintd successfully. I followed the Wiki to update my /etc/pam.d/system-local-login, /etc/pam.d/sudo, and several others. No matter what, though, it continues to only use my (typed) password for login AND sudo verification. I also added myself to the input group. Am I missing something?
Note that it WORKS when trying a command with su -c for whatever reason. I've included the pam.d file for that as well. (And, no, it does not work if I just copy and paste the contents of su into any of those other files.)
/etc/pam.d/system-local-login:
#%PAM-1.0
auth      sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth      include   system-login
account   include   system-login
password  include   system-login
session   include   system-login

/etc/pam.d/sudo:
#%PAM-1.0

auth    sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth    include    system-auth
account include    system-auth
session include    system-auth

/etc/pam.d/su
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_fprintd.so
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            required        pam_unix.so
account         required        pam_unix.so
session         required        pam_unix.so
password        include         system-auth

